# Flutter Firestore boolean value check

Tags: flutter

Well, I want to check if the profile is complete after creating the account so I added a bool to the firestore. When the user fills in all the data and clicks "complete" at the end, then bool "complete" will be true and I did it, but now I want to check before the user starts filling in the data if bool is true or false. If this is true, the user will be redirected to the dashboard, if it is false, he will have to complete all the data after logging in. User login details are stored in firebase and the rest of the information is stored in firestore.
If any more information is needed, I will try to specify it

I would like to check if the value is true or false before redirecting to "CreateProfile1 ();", if it's possible

```
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: ((context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(child: Text('Something went wrong!'));
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return CreateProfile1();
        } else {
          return AuthPage();
        }
      }),
    ));
  }
}
```

I was trying to save bool value into variable, but i've got this error

```
external static Never _throw(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace);
```

Here is this var, final actually

```
final complete = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('usersdData')
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .get()
      .then((value) {
    if ((value.data() as dynamic)['complete'] == true) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Cannot get the full context of your question. Please explain

Comment: I edited the post because the description is too long to add in the answer. And I'm sorry it took so long to answer, but I wasn't home